# How to make Python Crypto AES faster

Tags: python, encryption, aes, pycrypto

I'm looking for a very fast way for encrypting and decrypting short text snippets. Security is secondary in my use-case. Light encryption with a constant IV is fine. I'm currently doing this:

```
BS = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS)
unpad = lambda s : s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]

import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

iv = '0123456789012345'
def encrypt(raw, key):
    raw = pad(raw)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return base64.b64encode( cipher.encrypt( raw ) )

def decrypt(enc, key):
    enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return unpad(cipher.decrypt( enc ))

enc_text = encrypt('Hello World!','xyz1234567890abc')
print decrypt(enc_text, 'xyz1234567890abc')
```

How can I make this faster? Maybe by using another AES mode (MODE_CBC?), or is there a faster padding function, a faster way of hex-converting the output?

Comment: try http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why do you need this fast? Can you change to a compiled language like C or Java?

Comment: It has to be Python. Just realized, by using binascii (ASCII only is fine), I can speed up the function by about 7%. That's something.

Comment: pycrypto uses a native implementation of AES in C and supports AES-NI. There is nothing faster that can be done there. How fast do you want it? You could look for a python wrapper of a C implementation of TEA.

Comment: +1 for TEA. XXTEA is exactly what I'd love to use, however, this lead me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053117/python-xxtea-library-causes-segmentation-faults

Comment: [XTEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA).

Answer (score 1):

Counter mode (`AES.MODE_CTR`) will be faster for multi-block messages, as it can be parallelized for both encryption and decryption. `CBC` is serial on encryption because the resulting output of each block-cipher operation is fed as input to be `XOR` with the plaintext of the next block before encrypting. Because `CTR` generates a keystream by encrypting each (sequential) counter value with the key, it does not rely on the output of any previous block operation and can perform the tasks in parallel.

In addition, because `CTR` operates as a stream cipher, no message padding is required, so you'll save time on that operation in and out.

**Note: Don't re-use counters. You mentioned that confidentiality is a secondary concern here, but while re-using IVs in CBC mode is "bad", re-using counters in CTR mode is *end of the world* bad.** Just use a [sequential counter (literally `i++`) combined with 64 bits of the `ms since epoch start`](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/11362/12569) and you'll be fine. (See [Stream Reuse](https://cryptosmith.com/2008/05/31/stream-reuse/) or [Many Time Pad Attack](https://travisdazell.blogspot.in/2012/11/many-time-pad-attack-crib-drag.html) for good examples of why).